# update Android app to latest Android M

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to know a better way to updates my existing project to latest android M for testing purpose. Is there a better way than my current approach?

Here is what I am doing based on this [Preview SDK](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

1. Upgrade Android Studio.
2. Download SDK.
3. Update build.gradle to MNC.

so now, AS(android studio) told me I need to update my java to 1.7 due to `diamond operator is not supported in source 1.6`. Then some of my classes in the project reported `Package xxx does not exist`. **Does the error msg cause by API updates?** If so, that might give me a clue and i will find the corresponding API in android M to fix it.

for example, the following error happened only after the updates.

`Error:(43, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist`

I do know there is a doc for API changes, but I do want to ask you if this is a normal way to updates the APIs to the latest release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the error msg cause by API updates?

If you are referring to:

```
Error:(43, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
```

then yes, that was caused by the API update, as [the HttpClient APIs were removed in Android M](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client), after having been deprecated in Android 5.1.

> if this is a normal way to updates the APIs to the latest release?

Well, reading [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/index.html) before doing any of your aforementioned steps is a very good idea.

Developer previews are also different than regular OS releases, in that you should not be shipping apps compiled against a preview.

Otherwise, what you are describing is certainly the starting point. What changes you may want to make (e.g., for [the new permission system](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html)) will depend upon the nature of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. the purpose of this is to make my application compatible with latest android M and latest API. Meanwhile support minimum android 3. I think a if-else statement to retrieve machine android version and use the corresponding API. What do you say?

Comment: @Chi: "Meanwhile support minimum android 3" -- if you mean API Level 3, that is a complete waste of your time IMHO. If you mean Android 3.0, you may as well limit yourself to Android 4.0, as *very* few devices are still running Android 3.x. "I think a if-else statement to retrieve machine android version and use the corresponding API. What do you say?" -- that is a typical approach.